# Check if an email was replied to using Mailgun API

Tags: node.js, express, email, mailgun

I'm building a SAAS app that allows users to send email sequences, I want to stop the sequence when a user replies to an email sent by my app.

Based on what I found on the internet I should use **Mailgun Routes** to accomplish it.

I have all set up (Domain and MX records) but I couldn't forward emails to my server.

**What I want to accomplish is the following**:

1. **User A** uses this email address (*usera@example.com*)
2. **User B** uses this email address (*userb@lorem.com*)
3. **User A** sends an email using my platform, my platform calls *mailgun*
   API to send it
4. **User B** receives that email and hits reply
5. *Mailgun* notices that **User B** replies and forwards that reply to my
   server.

I do not own neither *example.com* nor *lorem.com* domains

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control neither, you can't. Set the Reply-To address to something you control and that's linked to Mailgun Routes, [check the Message-ID](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/product/tracking-replies-in-mailgun-or-any-other-email/) then [forward the e-mail](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-routes.html#actions) to user B.

Rather than using the Message-ID header, some people generate a unique Reply-To address (replies+a2c4e6@some-domain.tld) as the In-Reply-To header isn't guaranteed to be sent.

Comment: Thank you Rick, I think I'll go that route. If I set the Reply-To header, the to header will still show the User B as a receiver, right?

Comment: It depends on the e-mail client, but in most you'll see "From <userB>" with a separate line below it with "Reply-to: <your email>". When sending e-mail on behalf of someone else, do keep SPF in mind—your messages might end up in spam (this is unrelated to reply-to).